# How to retrieve records from mysql from different users

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a booking system using php and mysql database. The system has multiple users who can log in and make bookings so i want to know a way of selecting records based on users sessions. At the moment its only selecting all booking records which means users have access to all bookings.

I have a booking table which has booking records and a users table with users credentials.Is there also a way for selecting records from both tables

Comment: This is basic MySQL. Google "mysql join tutorial".

Comment: Can you post your tables structure? Basically you need a field to relate the booking to a user (something like "user_id") in the booking table

Comment: i have 2 tables which are bookings and users.  The bookings table has the following fields : bookingid, date, time, type, vehicle. The users table has: ID,username,password and email

Answer (score 1):

On your users table, you should have a unique id.

On your bookings table, you have a field user id. When you add a booking, you save the user id in to that field.

Then, when you want to retrieve bookings, you select records matching the specific user id.

Having a field for user id on the bookings table is called a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). It's the basis for a lot of what you do with sql. Setting it up this way allows you to do what's called a [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). This is where you get all the data from two or more tables, with the rows combined based on their key values. So in your case you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users,bookings WHERE bookings.id=users.id;
```

This will give you back records that have all the booking data, and all the user data for the user who made that booking. You could also do:

```
SELECT * FROM bookings where users.id=3;
```

Which would give you all the booking data for the user with id 3.

You can also match on other fields, but keep that foreign key as the join to guarantee that you always get the correct link between bookings and users eg.

```
SELECT * FROM users,bookings WHERE users.surname="Doe" AND bookings.id=users.id;
```

You can use it in reverse too - for example, if you want to get the user details for everyone who has a booking on a given date, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE bookings.date='03/03/2015' AND users.id=bookings.id;
```

As you can see, adding that user id to the bookings table opens up a lot of possibilities because it links your data together, allowing you to get data as a single record even if it's split over multiple tables.

Comment: i already have an id for users tables, would i need to use the same field in my bookings table? I am able to retrieve user details for all users based on user sessions. I am trying to follow the same concept for retrieving bookings from different users

Comment: Yes exactly - you put just the id from users in your bookings table, and that allows you then to user user/booking data almost as if it was in the same table. I added some detail about it to my answer above - hope it helps.

Comment: I want to select id, date and time from bookings table as well as the username and id from users. I want to username to be the users session and this should display bookings created by different users.  How would i write this as an sql statement to select these ?

Comment: The following is an example where i am able to retrieve details from different users in my database.   $sqlquery = "SELECT firstname, surname, email, contactTel FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['loggedInUser']."' ";  I am trying to follow this concept to select bookings made by different users in my database

Comment: also how would i display these details. At the moment i am using  while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){


  echo "<br> ID: ". $row["id"]. "   <br> Type: " . $row["Type"] ." <br> Date: ".$row["BookingDate"]."     <br> Time: ". $row["Timeslot"]. 
        //"<br> Vehicle: ".$row["Manufacture"]."<br>";
  
 

but it doesnt show anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique ID for each user in your database. Use a `Primary Key` and set it to Auto Increment.

After checking for valid credentials on login, grab their ID from the database and store it in a session variable.

Create your bookings table with a user ID column. Assign a user ID to a booking. When you want to query their bookings, include their user ID in the query.

Comment: i am currently storing their username in a session variable